# ReactJS. How to get the ClassList and other DIV props by ref in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I try to add an extra class to the classList of the some `i` element, but now I fall into the problem with standart `div.classList.add('you-class')` method, because when I try to use it with React ref system - I even got an error - `cannot get classList of null`... Why?

```
export class Cd extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.refCDImg = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    console.log( this.refCDImg.current ); // all good
    this.refCDImg.current.classList.add('disk-image-large--waiting'); // error

    return(
       // ...some code
        <i ref={this.refCDImg} className={'d-img-large'} />
// ...some code
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are consoling before the component is mounted because of which the node is undefined, try consoling in componentDidmount. Here is the working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/7162l1ll40